# SQL UPDATE statement error in python code

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to write a python function that updates a postgres database. The table to be updated is given (department)
Below is the function I wrote:

```
def modify_dept_budget(deptName, newBudget):
  connection = None
  try:
    connection  = connector() # This is a function I wrote to connect so I can hide my credentials.
    cursor1 = connection.cursor()
    query1 = f"select dept_name from department"
    cursor1.execute(query1)
    results1 = cursor1.fetchall()
    results1 = [result[0] for result in results1]
    if deptName in results1:
        idx = results1.index(deptName)
        print(results1[idx])
        cursor2 = connection.cursor()
        query = f"UPDATE department SET budget = %s WHERE dept_name == {deptName}"
        cursor2.execute(query, [newBudget])
        cursor3 = connection.cursor()
        cursor3.execute(f'SELECT * FROM department')
        results2 = cursor3.fetchall()
        headers = [item[0] for item in cursor3.description]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data = results2, columns = headers)
        print(df)
  except(Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
  finally:
    if connection:
      cursor1.close()
      cursor2.close()
      cursor3.close()
      connection.close()
```

When I run `modify_dept_budget('Music', 85000)`, I get the following error:

```
Music
column "music" does not exist
LINE 1: ...PDATE department SET budget = 85000 WHERE dept_name == Music
                                                                  ^

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-16e7278e3358> in <module>
----> 1 modify_dept_budget('Music', 85000)

<ipython-input-76-80361b6ddf35> in modify_dept_budget(deptName, newBudget)
     26       cursor1.close()
     27       cursor2.close()
---> 28       cursor3.close()
     29       connection.close()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor3' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: Use the proper parameter passing as shown here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). The issue is `deptName` not being passed in as a properly quoted string e.g. 'Music'. While you are there read the note that starts `Warning Never, never, NEVER ...` for why you don't want to do what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, SQL does not use the double `==` for the equality test.  Just plain `=`.  Second, that string literal needs to be quoted.  Unless you need a table name or a field name, you won't be using f-strings with SQL.  So, do:

```
        query = "UPDATE department SET budget = %s WHERE dept_name = %s"
        cursor2.execute(query, [newBudget, deptName])
```